# Can anyone with the passphrase decrypt a file encrypted with GnuPG plus the symmetric flag?

Tags: linux, security, encryption, gnupg

Say that I own Laptop A. Say that, on Laptop A, I encrypt a file using the command:

```sh
gpg --symmetric my_file.txt
```

And say that I then install that encrypted file on a USB stick.

Now suppose that six months pass, during which time Laptop A breaks, and is replaced by Laptop B. Will I be able to decrypt the file on Laptop B, using the passphrase, perhaps using `gpg --decrypt`?

Would the situation change if I used a command such as `gpg --encrypt` or `gpg --encrypt --symmetric` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The passphrase is sufficient.

In the
[answer by Andrey Tyukin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/662662/17660)
I found this example:

> ````
> #!/bin/bash
>
> echo "Some important content" > a.txt [ -f a.txt.gpg ] && rm a.txt.gpg
> [ -f b.txt ] && rm b.txt
>
> echo "secret" | gpg --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --output a.txt.gpg
> --symmetric a.txt echo "secret" | gpg --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --output b.txt --decrypt a.txt.gpg
>
> echo "------------------------- a.txt" cat a.txt
>
> echo "------------------------- b.txt" cat b.txt
>
> diff a.txt b.txt && echo "Files have the same content" ```
> ````

You can encrypt messages using the “--encrypt” flag, which
encrypts the message using the recipient’s public key,
giving additional security.

From
[Encrypting and decrypting documents](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x110.html) :

> To encrypt a document the option --encrypt is used. You must have the
> public keys of the intended recipients. The software expects the name
> of the document to encrypt as input or, if omitted, on standard input.
> The encrypted result is placed on standard output or as specified
> using the option --output. The document is compressed for additional
> security in addition to encrypting it.
>
> ```
> alice% gpg --output doc.gpg --encrypt --recipient blake@cyb.org doc
> ```
>
> The --recipient option is used once for each recipient and takes an
> extra argument specifying the public key to which the document should
> be encrypted. The encrypted document can only be decrypted by someone
> with a private key that complements one of the recipients' public
> keys. In particular, you cannot decrypt a document encrypted by you
> unless you included your own public key in the recipient list.
>
> To decrypt a message the option --decrypt is used. You need the
> private key to which the message was encrypted. Similar to the
> encryption process, the document to decrypt is input, and the
> decrypted result is output.

So to decrypt an encrypted file would need the private key
for one of the recipients' public keys.
Without such a key, you will be unable to decrypt unless
you included your own public key in the recipient list.

Comment: So, if I use the `--encrypt` option, and I then lose my public key, I wouldn't be able to decrypt my file, even if I could remember the passphrase? If you make that issue a bit clearer, then I will gladly accept your excellent answer.

Comment: I hope the added last paragraph clarifies the issue.

Comment: Looks like the double hyphen in `--encrypt` got converted to an en dash by autocorrect or something like that. (It's too small a change for a suggested edit.)

Answer (score 5):

> Would the situation change if I used a command such as 
> `gpg --encrypt --symmetric` instead?

Combining both options creates "a message that may be decrypted via a secret key ***or*** a passphrase" - only one is required.

Using only `--symmetric` uses only a passphrase, and needs only the *same* passphrase to decrypt.

Using only `--encrypt` uses only a public key, and needs only that keypair's secret key to decrypt.